# Having problem to convert Vb method into C# method

Tags: c#, vb.net

I wont to convert this VB method below into c# method. This method should calculate number of days for Rent and then multiply that number with txtRate textbox, so I can get the final number (txtTotal) which can be after stored into data grid view.

VB Method

```
Sub GetTotal()
    Try
        Dim day As Integer
        day = DateDiff("d", Now.Date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"), DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))
        day += 1
        lblDay.Text = day
        txtTotal.Text = Format(day * CDbl(txtRate.Text), "#,##0.00")
    Catch ex As Exception
        txtTotal.Text = "0.00"
    End Try
End Sub
```

I did not find any similar method like vb DateDiff is and that is the main problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a few options to calculate date difference. In C# you can import the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace and invoking the DateDiff method. 'using Microsoft.VisualBasic'. Normally the IDE should suggest the import of the namespace. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Some advice: Accept the inputs as parameters and return the result instead of accessing the controls directly. This method is tightly bound to the UI but what it's doing has nothing to do with the UI. Don't just convert it from one language to another. Segregate the interactions with the controls from the logic. Your code will be easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You can just subtract one DateTime from another. It realizes a TimeSpan, which has a TotalDays property:

```
//if the date time picker date is in the future 
(dateTimePicker1.Value - DateTime.Now).TotalDays
```

TotalDays is a decimal number, like 1.5. One thing to note with a lot of DateDiff functions (SQLServer, VBA, and maybe hence also VB - I can't quite remember) is that they give you the number of times the interval has changed between the dates which is subtly different to a time span

For example asking SQLServer's DateDiff for the years between 2020-12-31 23:59:59 and 2021-01-01 00:00:01 will say "1 year" because the year rocker up from 2020 to 2021, even though only 2 seconds have passed between the two dates

As such if you do specifically need that "imprecise" behavior, you might want to carefully assess whether a TineSpan route (which is very accurate and would give a TotalDays of eg 0.0000235 for the 2 seconds example a live whereas DateDiff would have said 1)

Comment: I managed to solve part of the problem. My curren solution is this : private void GetTotal()
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime d2 = dtReturn.Value;

                TimeSpan diff = d2.Subtract(d1);

                lblDay.Text = diff.Days.ToString("0.00");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                txtTotal.Text = "0.00";
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve firs part of the problem. My current solution is this :

private void GetTotal()
{

```
       try

        {
            DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime d2 = dtReturn.Value;

            TimeSpan diff = d2.Subtract(d1);

            lblDay.Text = diff.Days.ToString("0.00"); //here I get number of Rent days
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            txtTotal.Text = "0.00";
        }
    }
```

Now I need to multiply Value from lblDay with another txt fild (txtRate) so I can get a Total Value wich is stored into txtTotal Field. After I need to store transaction into data grid view

Comment: To be clear, I wont to do something like this  : txtTotal.Text = lblDay.Text * txtRate.Text;  but I have problems with casting - operator * cannot be applied to operands of type string and string